# Modified BFS Time Complexity

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

so BFS has a complexity of O(|V| + |E|) when the queue is implemented like this:

```
ENQUEUE(Q,source_vertex)
while Q != NULL
   u=DEQUEUE(Q)
   for each v in AdjacencyList[u]
     if v not yet visited
        Make v visited
        ENQUEUE(Q,v)
```

If I modify the code to add all vertices in adjacency list of u to the Queue like this:

```
ENQUEUE(Q,source_vertex)
while Q != NULL
   u=DEQUEUE(Q)
   for each v in AdjacencyList[u]
      if v not finalized            
         ENQUEUE(Q,v)
   make u finalized
```

Will the running time still remain O(|V| + |E|)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the graph has a cycle, you might enqueue the same node over and over again, causing and infinite loop. Or do you mean something different?

Comment: Hey Yeah I realized that so I edited the code now.

Comment: You got conflicting answers.  I suggest you try it with complete graphs of increasing size to prove to yourself that the answer is *no*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you have a clique of n nodes (let’s number them 1, 2, ..., n and assume the adjacency lists store them in this order) and you run the modified algorithm starting at node 1. Node 1 will enqueue nodes 2, 3, ..., n for a total of Θ(n) work. The queue now looks like this:

> 2, 3, 4, ..., n

When you then process node 2, it will look at all its edges for Θ(n) more work, then enqueue nodes 3, 4, 5, ..., n in the queue. Our queue now looks like this:

> 3, 4, 5, ..., n, 3, 4, 5, ..., n

We now process node 3, which looks at all its edges for Θ(n) work, then enqueues node’s 4, 5, 6, ..., n, so our queue looks like this:

> 4, 5, 6, ..., n, 3, 4, 5, ..., n, 4, 5, 6, ..., n

The pattern here is that we end up enqueuing many copies of each node in the graph. In fact, we’ll end up with a total of Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) total nodes in the queue over time, and we do Θ(n) work per node. That means the total work done is Θ(n<sup>3</sup>) for this graph, which exceeds the O(m + n) time bound of the original BFS implementation.

As a result, this new implementation may be asymptotically slower than a regular BFS.

Comment: Hey what if the input graph is a directed acyclic graph?

Comment: Imagine a complete directed acyclic graph, again number the nodes 1, 2, 3, ..., n so that everything points at all the nodes after it. Node 2 is inserted once, node 3 is inserted twice, node 4 is inserted 3 times, etc. Also, node number k has (n - 1 - k) edges leaving it. The total work done is then 1(n - 2) + 2(n - 3) + 3(n - 4) + 4(n - 5) + ... + (n - 3) 2 + (n - 2) 1 + (n - 1)0. If you work out this sum, it comes out to Theta(n^3) again, so this is still slower than a regular BFS.

Comment: Change the example to add edges to the queue and process the non-finalised end of the edge - you will find that each edge is added to the queue once (and the non-finalised end of the edge is the same as the vertex in your example) but since you have a complete graph on `n` vertices you will have `n(n-1)/2` edges so the algorithm is still `O(|V| + |E|)` it is just `|E|` is the same order as `|V|²`.

Comment: @MT0 for the undirected case ended that are already processed won’t get put back into the queue, but will still be rescanned by the inner loop. It’s that work spent reprocessing edges multiple times that adds up and causes problems. Unless I’m mistaken?

Comment: @MT0 Though in terms of the total number of enqueues, I'm completely with you. That part of the argument is totally correct.

Comment: After a lot of consideration - I agree with you that the algorithm will reprocess the adjacency list for each vertex multiple times and is `O(VE)` and not `O(V+E)`. The simple fix is to add a check that `u` is not finalized before processing its adjacency list.

Answer (score 1):

Lets change your algorithm to add edges to the queue (since that is implicitly what you are doing - except you are only viewing the opposite vertex when you add it to the queue and not the entire edge):

```
ENQUEUE( Q,(NULL->source_vertex) )            # start with a dummy edge
WHILE Q != NULL
  (s->u)=DEQUEUE(Q)
  for each (u->v) in AdjacencyList[u]   
    if v not finalized
      ENQUEUE(Q,(u->v))
  make u finalized
```

Each edge will be considered for enqueuing twice as `(u->v)` and `(v->u)`. When the first vertex of the edge `u` is visited then each adjacent edge will be put onto the queue and then `u` is finalised. When `v` is visited then the edge `(v->u)` will be considered but, since `u` has already been finalised, will not be added to the queue; so each edge will only be enqueued once (in one direction but not in the other).

The problem with the algorithm is that it does not check whether the vertex it is about to process has already been finalized and will reprocess it for each edge on the queue iterating over all adjacent edges again making your algorithm `O(|V||E|)` (rather than `O(|V| + |E|)`).

A simple fix would be:

```
ENQUEUE( Q,(NULL->source_vertex) )            # start with a dummy edge
WHILE Q != NULL
  (s->u)=DEQUEUE(Q)
  if u not finalized
    for each (u->v) in AdjacencyList[u]
      if v not finalized
        ENQUEUE(Q,(u->v))
    make u finalized
```

Also, both versions of your algorithm will start with one vertex and then process each edge within the same connected component - however they will only perform a full BFS on a connected graph. If you have multiple disconnected components then you would need to use:

```
for each source_vertex in Graph
  if source_vertex not visited/finalised
    call your_algorithm( source_vertex )
```

Which would then be `O(|V| + |E|)` and would visit all vertices regardless of whether the graph was connected or not.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, the runtime complexity is also `O(|V|+|E|)`. The second version just postpones the *finalization* step (which could also be termed as *visiting*) to the next iteration; neither the number of recursive calls nor the sequence of vertices changes.

Comment: wouldn't it be infinite loop for cycles?

Comment: I don't think so; `u` gets finalized at the end of the loop, and a finalized node is never put in the queue, so the queue must finally get empty.

Comment: I think I have a counterexample to this claim. Can you check my answer to see if I missed anything?